# Windows 7 Media Center overscan settings for NVIDIA graphics card

Tags: windows-7, nvidia-graphics-card, windows-media-center, overscan

Does anyone know how to change the overscan parameters of a CRT TV on a component out from an EVGA NVIDIA GeForce 8400 GS graphics card?

On my Windows XP machine there is nView; on my previous Ubuntu box there was an overscan slider. There doesn't seem to be any way of changing it on a Windows 7 machine.

There is no "resize the desktop" command as far as I can tell.

Comment: You did install the drivers from nvidia.com, did you..?

Comment: Drivers are current. v270.61

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting in the nVidia appliation called `Resize My Desktop` in Display>>Adjust Desktop Size & Resolution, you may need to enable an 'advanced options' view to see this.

This has horizontal & vertical sliders with a test graphic to scale the desktop to the display.

[image: nVidia desktop resizing]

Comment: As far as I can tell, that isn't an option. I get the option to move the dektop around on my primary display, but not eh reseize it, and no options at all with regards to my HDTV display (component out)

Comment: Ahh, I saw component but didn't see CRT.  I resume then the nVidia app doesn't even offer you any of the HDTV options?